# Empty error message when processing SSAS Multidimention Cube

Tags: ssas, olap

When processing an SSAS Multidimensional Cube's dimensions from an SSIS package the task repeatedly fails with an empty error message:

[image]

If I do a manual processing, with default settings, everything seems to work. The default setting are:

- Processing order: Parallel
- Transaction mode: (Default)
- Dimension errors: (Default)
- Dimension key error log path: (Default)
- Process affected objects: Do not process

The SSIS task runs with the following settings:

- **Processing order: Sequential**
- **Transaction mode: All in one transaction**
- Dimension errors: (Default)
- Dimension key error log path: (Default)
- Process affected objects: Do not process

Today I run the manual processing with the same setting form the Task, and got the result from the image.

Can someone help me understand what is the meaning of the empty error message? And how does the Processing order and Transaction mode affects error messages?